# How do you run multiple 'Test Movies' in Flash CS4 IDE? (Need the Sandbox Mode)

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I'm making a binary socket server for Flash and I'm trying to figure out a way to run Multiple clients in a local environment for testing purposes.

Tried to run the exported flash movie in my browser (to open multiple tabs of flash swf) but I just could not figure out how to solve the cross-domain problem.

I'm running my server right from my PC (localhost) and just simply want to test my darn Flash document multiple times so I can simulate multiple clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a folder somewhere on you computer. Usually I call it **C:/FlashSandbox/**

Then add it to the allowed file paths in the [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) ("edit locations" dropdown). Then just add your SWF to this folder, and you should be able to access your server.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate!  Can't believe I didn't stumble upon this while Googling.

Comment: It's a tricky thing. I can't even remember how i figured it out back in the day.